# Elastic Beanstalk does not recognize IAM role with policies "AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth" and "AWSElasticBeanstalkService"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to host Metabase using Metabase using Elastic Beanstalk (EBK) accordnig to this [tutorial](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/installation-and-operation/running-metabase-on-elastic-beanstalk). On environment creation, as I follow the instructions, it gives an error log below, also available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUGMP.png):

`The instance profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role associated with the environment does not exist.`

I suppose, the error regards IAM roles. I created a role with permissions `AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth` and `AWSElasticBeanstalkService`. However, the error persists. In case you have already stumbled on this same error, please, say the necessary steps to fix this instance profile inexistence.